# How do I one hot encode along a specific dimension using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, one-hot-encoding

I have a tensor of size `[3, 15, 136]`, where:

- `3 is batch size`
- `15 - sequence length` and
- `136 is tokens`

I want to one-hot my tensor using the probabilities in the `tokens` dimension (136). To do so I want to extract the tokens dimension for each letter in sequence length and put `1` to the largest possibility and mark all other tokens as `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PyTorch's [`one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html) function to achieve this:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F

t = torch.rand(3, 15, 136)

F.one_hot(t.argmax(dim=2), 136)
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work for me with one exception. I masked my tensor before this operation, so thus padded letters have 0 in the whole dimension. And somehow the `F.one_hot(torch.argmax(t, dim=2), 136)` chooses the first 0 to be one. Should I mask it once more after the 'argmax`?

Comment: @julliet yes, if there are multiple maximal values (e.g. all are 0) then `argmax` returns the index of the first maximal value (i.e. the first element).

Comment: I can apply masking there once more after `argmax`, is it correct?

Comment: @julliet yep :)