# Convert one-hot encoded dimension into the index of position of 1

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, argmax

I have a tensor of three dimensions `[batch_size, sequence_length, number_of_tokens]`.
The last dimension is one-hot encoded. I want to receive a tensor of two dimensions, where `sequence_length` consists of the index position of '1' of the `number_of_tokens` dimension.

For example, to turn a tensor of shape `(2, 3, 4)`:

```
[[[0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]]
[[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]]]
```

into a tensor of shape `(2, 3)` where `number_of_tokens` dimension is converted into the `1`'s position:

```
[[1, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 2]]
```

I'm doing it to prepare the model result to compare to reference answer when computing loss, I hope it is correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original tensor is as specified in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387722/how-do-i-one-hot-encode-along-a-specific-dimension-using-pytorch), you can bypass the one-hot encoding and directly use the argmax:

```py
t = torch.rand(2, 3, 4)
t = t.argmax(dim=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
res = x.argmax(axis = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want through successive **list comprehension**:

```
x=[[[0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1]],
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0]]]

y=[[ell2.index(1) for ell2 in ell1] for ell1 in x]

print(y) # prints [[1, 0, 3], [0, 0, 2]]
```

which iterates over the elements of your main tensor and at each element, returns the list of "1" indices in the components of that element.